# Matching subset of two columns of two different dataframes

Tags: python-3.x

Comparing specific columns from two different dataframes. Counting if subset of both dataframe is matching or not matching.

Condition:
If **any element** of file `small['genes of cluster']` is matching with the `big['genes of cluster']`, output should be: `match: 1`.

For below example only `OR4F16` is matching to both dataframes. 
So Output: `match: 1; unmatch: 3.`

```
    file1: big <tab separated>
    cl    nP    genes of cluster
     1    11    DDX11L1, MIR6859-3, WASH7P, MIR1302-2, FAM138C, FAM138F, FAM138A, OR4F5, LOC729737, LOC102725121, FAM138D
     2     4    OR4F16, OR4F3, OR4F29, LOC100132287
     3    64    LOC100133331, LOC100288069, FAM87B, LINC00115, LINC01128, FAM41C, LINC02593, SAMD11
     4     7    GNB1, CALML6, TMEM52, CFAP74, GABRD, LOC105378591, PRKCZ


    file2: small <tab separated>
    cl    nP    genes of cluster
     1    11    A, B, C, D
     2     4    OR4F16, X, Y, Z
```

**My Code: Python3**

```
def genes_coordinates(big, small):
    b = pd.read_csv(big, header=0, sep="\t")
    s = pd.read_csv(small, header=0, sep="\t")

    match = 0
    unmatch = 0

    for index, row in b.iterrows():
        if row[row['genes of cluster'].isin(s['genes of cluster'])]:
            match+1
        else:
            unmatch+1
    print("match: ", match, "\nunmatch: ", unmatch)

genes_coordinates('big','small')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with a pandas.merge() followed by counting by list comprehension.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'cl':[1,2], 'nP':[11,4], 'gene of cluster':[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['OR4F16', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'cl':[1,2,3,4], 'nP':[11,4,64,7], 'gene of cluster':[['DDX11L1', 'MIR6859-3', 'WASH7P', 'MIR1302-2', 'FAM138C', 'FAM138F', 'FAM138A', 'OR4F5', 'LOC729737', 'LOC102725121', 'FAM138D'], ['OR4F16', 'OR4F3', 'OR4F29', 'LOC100132287'], ['LOC100133331', 'LOC100288069', 'FAM87B', 'LINC00115', 'LINC01128', 'FAM41C', 'LINC02593', 'SAMD11'], ['GNB1', 'CALML6', 'TMEM52', 'CFAP74', 'GABRD', 'LOC105378591', 'PRKCZ']]})

df_m = df1.merge(df2, on=['cl', 'nP'], how='outer')
>>>df_m

   cl  nP  gene of cluster_x                                  gene of cluster_y
0   1  11       [A, B, C, D]  [DDX11L1, MIR6859-3, WASH7P, MIR1302-2, FAM138...
1   2   4  [OR4F16, X, Y, Z]              [OR4F16, OR4F3, OR4F29, LOC100132287]
2   3  64                NaN  [LOC100133331, LOC100288069, FAM87B, LINC00115...
3   4   7                NaN  [GNB1, CALML6, TMEM52, CFAP74, GABRD, LOC10537...

# An np.nan value is an outright 'unmatch'
found = []
for x in df_m.index:
    if isinstance(df_m.iloc[x]['gene of cluster_x'], float):
        found.append(0)
    else:
        if isinstance(df_m.iloc[x]['gene of cluster_y'], float):
            found.append(0)
        elif any([y in df_m.iloc[x]['gene of cluster_y'] for y in df_m.iloc[x]['gene of cluster_x']]):
            found.append(1)
        else:
            found.append(0)
# The counts
match = sum(found)
unmatch = len(found) - match
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help. 
     code is working on sample. With real file: TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable. 
Real file: No of col in real files are different....

file1: big (columns: 6)... 
cluster number...      
number of genes per cluster... 
number of promoters per cluster... 
flag... 
genes in cluster number of promoter binding TFs in cluster... 

file 2: small (columns: 5)... 
cluster number... 
number of genes per cluster...
number of promoters per cluster... 
flag... 
genes in cluster...

Comment: @HimanshuSingh Did you manage to merge the 2 dataframes on the _cl_ and _nP_ keys on your actual files?

Comment: Yes it is merged properly

Comment: @HimanshuSingh I have updated my answer. The error that you got earlier was due to indices from the small file not being found in the big file. I have therefore, included an additional layer of check for np.nan in that column

Comment: It is working fine. Thank you very much for your help. Please just correct me if I am wrong.In   "if isinstance(df_m.iloc[x]['gene of cluster_x'], float)": float is used to check if its not number?

Comment: @HimanshuSingh Yes, that's right. Actually, it's better to check by using `pd.isnull()`, for nan values i.e. `pd.isnull(df_m.iloc[x]['gene of cluster_x'])`